# MissingMethodException after upgrading to Grails 2.2

Tags: grails, groovy, version, upgrade

After upgrading to Grails 2.2, I get this exception

Class: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException`

Message:

> No signature of method: static org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

The exception occurs on index.gsp only - how can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After the upgrade, the Grails version can no longer be retrieved using `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()`.

Open index.gsp and change the line which says "Groovy version" to

`<li>Groovy version: ${GroovySystem.getVersion()}</li>`

to get rid of the error message.

Comment: i'm upgrading from Grails 2.1.1 to 2.2.0 and this was very helpful